# PHP CRYPT_BLOWFISH install

Tags: php, crypt

I want to use crypt() CRYPT_BLOWFISH hashing. Since PHP version is 5.2.14, CRYPT_BLOWFISH is 0.

So, I install CRYPT_BLOWFISH using the following command:
pear install Crypt_Blowfish-1.1.0RC2

It shows Crypt_Blowfish-1.1.0RC2 is installed. However, echo CRYPT_BLOWFISH is still 0.
How can I use CRYPT_BLOWFISH hashing if I do not upgrade my PHP version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEAR modules don't add features to stock PHP, so it isn't going to affect constants like `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`, nor can you use the standard functions. You'll need to use the equivalents from the `Crypt_Blowfish` package.

There's a [usage example](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/docs/latest/Crypt_Blowfish/Crypt_Blowfish.html) on the PEAR docs for Crypt_Blowfish.

Comment: Right. I check the example. It initializes a Crypt_Blowfish instance. What I want is to make PHP crypt() use Crypt_Blowfish hashing. As the manual said, I just need to craft a salt as '$2a2$', then crypt() will use Crypt_Blowfish hashing. But pear gives me a Crypt_Blowfish instance, how can I use it in crypt()?

Comment: You won't be able to use the native `crypt()` call. You will need to use the PEAR package's functions instead. The `crypt()` function doesn't have any way of knowing about the `Crypt_Blowfish` package.

Comment: Another question I have is that I activate suhosin simulation mode. It will violations. So where is the logging?